# How to search for words with asterisks and wildcards (e.g., exampl*) in R (word appearance in a data frame)

Tags: r, nlp, stringr, tidytext

I wrote a code to count the appearance of words in a data frame:

```
Items <-  c('decid*','head', 'heads')
df1<-data.frame(Items)
words<- c('head', 'heads', 'decided', 'decides', 'top', 'undecided')
df_main<-data.frame(words)
item <- vector() 
count <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(unique(Items))){ 
item[i] <- Items[i] 
count[i]<- sum(df_main$words  == item[i])} 
word_freq <- data.frame(cbind(item, count))
word_freq
```

However, the results are like this:

|  | item | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | decid* | 0 |
| 2 | head | 1 |
| 3 | heads | 1 |

As you see, it does not correctly count for "decid*". The actual results I expect should be like this:

|  | item | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | decid* | 2 |
| 2 | head | 1 |
| 3 | heads | 1 |

I think I need to change the item word (decid*) format, however, I could not figure it out. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `decid*` as regex pattern. `==` looks for an exact match, you may use `grepl` to look for a particular pattern.

I have used `sapply` as an alternative to `for` loop.

```
result <- stack(sapply(unique(df1$Items), function(x) {
  if(grepl('*', x, fixed = TRUE)) sum(grepl(x, df_main$word))
  else sum(x == df_main$words)
}))

result
# values    ind
#1      2 decid*
#2      1   head
#3      1  heads
```

Comment: To me it look like `head` should return a value of 1, since there is no wildcard at the end. The author code return 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think OP wants combination of pattern and exact match. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as an alternative approach altogether: instead of creating a new dataframe `word_freq`, why not create a new column in `df_main`(if that's your "main" dataframe) which indicates the number of matches of your (apparently key)`Items`. Also, that column will not actually contain **counts** because the input column `words` only contains a single word each. So the question is not how many matches are there for each row but whether there is a **match** in the first place. That can be indicated by `grepl`in `base R`or `str_detect`in `stringr`

**EDIT**:

Given the newly posted input data

```
Items <-  c('decid*','head', 'heads')
df1<-data.frame(Items)
words<- c('head', 'heads', 'decided', 'decides', 'top', 'undecided')
df_main<-data.frame(words)
```

and the OP's wish to have the matches in `df_main`, the solution might be this:

```
library(stringr)
df_main$Items_match <- +str_detect(df_main$words, str_c(Items, collapse = "|"))
```

Result:

```
df_main
      words Items_match
1      head           1
2     heads           1
3   decided           1
4   decides           1
5       top           0
6 undecided           1
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Ruehlemann Thanks for your help. I want the count of df1$Items in df_main. So, the results will show the df1$Items and their frequency in df_main. Can you please help with this?

Comment: I've edited the solution to fit the new input data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(count =sum(str_detect(df_main$words,
     str_c("\\b", str_replace(Items, fixed("*"), ".*" ), "\\b")))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Items  count
  <chr>  <int>
1 decid*     2
2 head       1
3 heads      1
```

Comment: Hi @akrun Thanks for your help. I want the count of df1$Items in df_main. So, the results will show the df1$Items and their frequency in df_main. It is important to get the correct results as the second table in the question. Could you please help with this?